# Replacing Keys in maps ,

Tags: java, if-statement, dictionary, iterator, key-value

I have made a program that makes a new map and takes the input from the user and fill the map...

Then I inverted the map keys/values and made a new map with it...

The only thing I'm stuck with , which is the hard part ... is to check if there are duplicates in the "Values" , if so ... I want to keep 1 only that corresponds to the smaller value of its key...
if I have for example , 12=13 , 8=13 , I want to put the 8=13 in my 2nd inverted map and remove the 12=13.

```
public class
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(System.out);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    Map<String,String> normal = new HashMap<String,String>();

    output.println("Enter your map, one key-value pair per line,");
    output.println("comma-separated. Use empty line as sentinel.");

    for ( String entry = input.nextLine(); entry.length() !=0;
        entry = input.nextLine())
    {
    int comma = entry.indexOf(",");
    String key = entry.substring(0,comma);
    String value = entry.substring(comma+1);
    normal.put(key,value);

    }
    output.println(normal);

    Map<String,String> reverse = new HashMap<String,String>();

    for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : normal.entrySet())
    {

        String keyY = entry.getKey();
        String valueE = entry.getValue();
        reverse.put(valueE,keyY);



    }
    output.println(reverse);

}
 }
```

Comment: It isn't really clear what you wan't, maybe give a code example?

Comment: Before entering a key/values in the second Map, check if the key already exists?

Comment: My apologies, here is the code..

Comment: I'm a bit confused -- you want to keep the key-value entry where the key is smaller, as if it's a number.  But instead of using a Map<Integer, Integer> you are using a Map<String, String>.  If your map is storing Strings, there is no guarantee that your keys can be converted to numbers.  What if instead of "8"="13" and "12"="13", you have "hello"="13" and "hi"="13"?  Which one would you want to keep?
Or did you actually mean to use a map of Numbers instead of a map of Strings?

Comment: @TJamesBoone 
to be honest , i am supposed to use Map<Integer,Integer> but i dont really know how to get the inputs from the user ... using strings allow me to search for the comma and the 2 numbers you know.. i'm certain there is a way but i couldn't figure it out so i followed this method writtne on the book. 
so the inputs will be numbers for sure, and there will be duplicates of values for sure... i need first to determine the duplicates of values ( i tried doing that by getValues() and it worked ) but then i couldn't replace the coressponding key smaller key :( i searched the whole API...

Comment: I gave an answer, hopefully it helps.  :)
By the way, I think when you pasted your sample code in your question, the name of your class got deleted, so you'll want to edit your question and add the name of your class so that your code compiles.  I guessed in my answer what the name of the class might be.

Comment: @TJamesBoone your answer works perfectly! i couldn't think of this method in hours, however, i made a mistake by making a String Map, the calculations works and output make sense , but the order is messed up ovbiously cuz i used String map, now how can i possibly use Integer map and take the input from the user, i know how to make an Integer map in general but i can't locate the comma, first and 2nd number to assign them to Key,values ... How can i accomplish such a thing?,,,

Comment: @AymanAbuassonon I saw that you posted the above comment as another question, so I answered it there.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would seem to be to look at the reverse map in each iteration of the for loop to see if it already has an entry with the key `valueE` in it.  If it does, see if the new potential value of `keyY` is smaller, and if so put it in the map (by doing so you will replace the old value).

You can use `Integer.parseInt(whateverString)` to convert the `String` values to `int`s for comparison.

Finally, if the current value for the entry is null (which in this context would mean no previous entry exists), then put the new value in the map.

So, like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class KeyValueSwitcher {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        PrintStream output=new PrintStream(System.out);
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);


        Map<String, String>normal=new HashMap<String, String>();

        output.println("Enter your map, one key-value pair per line,");
        output.println("comma-separated. Use empty line as sentinel.");

        for(String entry=input.nextLine();entry.length()!=0;
        entry=input.nextLine()) {
            int comma=entry.indexOf(",");
            String key=entry.substring(0,comma);
            String value=entry.substring(comma+1);
            normal.put(key,value);

        }
        output.println(normal);

        Map<String, String>reverse=new HashMap<String, String>();

        for(Map.Entry<String, String>entry:normal.entrySet()) {

            String keyY=entry.getKey();
            String valueE=entry.getValue();
            // check to see if we've already put an entry in the reverse map for this key.
            String existingReverseValue = reverse.get(valueE);
            if(existingReverseValue != null) {
                // We have, so let's see if the value is greater or less
                int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(existingReverseValue);
                int potentialNewValue = Integer.parseInt(keyY);
                if(potentialNewValue < currentValue) {
                    // Old reverse value is greater, so replace with new reverse value
                    reverse.put(valueE, keyY);
                }
            } else {
                // No previous reverse value exists, so add new reverse value
                reverse.put(valueE,keyY);
            }
        }
        output.println(reverse);
    }
}
```